# How to draw chart with high point density(>1 point per px) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, fragment-shader, shaderlab

I have big array of values/samples, and i need to draw wave chart in uGUI for it. So i have points with same interval at the coordinate x and i should connect them. I tried to draw it by few methods, but i always have problems when i need to draw more than 1 point pixel or per line thickness.

The problem arises because the standard solutions look at the nearest points by coordinates, while ignoring the points inside the segment, so it creates some unexpected artifacts, like cut of line. I tried line renderer it works just with low line thickness, and a little bad for uGUI. I tried Xiaoling Wu algo for Texture2D.SetPixel, but it turns into shreds when the distance between points on x is very small. Somehow it just so happens that GL.Lines draws lines good, but doesn't have line thickness and works bad with uGUI(i need always write it to render texture). So now i trying Shader Lab, and standart doublesmoothstep algo works bad too.

So is there some solution for fragment shader or i need try something anothing to solve problem?

Comment: Reduce the number of points.  Take an average at a specified interval or do some other post processing.  You physically cannot see the difference if the sample density is that high, so there is no point in trying to draw them all.

Comment: @hijinxbassist, its bad solution because i can lost some important points. For example i can have 2 near by X points, but far by Y. I found largest triangle algo, but it is not perfect

Comment: You could set a delta threshold that if passed would not remove or average the point.